# Fourier transform in two dimensions, Green's function for Schrodinger equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, integration, greens-functions

I want to calculate this Fourier transform: $$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \mbox{d}k \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \mbox{d}\varphi~ k \frac{e^{i \vec{k} \cdot(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')}}{k^2+B} $$ which will be 2D Green's function. How do I calculate this? My first problem is scalar product $ \vec{k} \cdot(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')$. Is it $|k||x-x'|\cos\varphi$ ? If yes, then which contour do I use? I can't really use half-circle because my integral is from 0 to infinity and my function isn't symmetric. Is there any other way to compute Green's function in two dimensions for Schrodinger's equation?

Comment: Correct form for the scalar product, yes. As for contours, I think you can try to use the branch cut method to integrate.

Comment: Agreed. Look at the *n* =0 , shifted τ second formula in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals), to get $\int d\phi \exp(ikr\cos\phi)=2\pi J_0(kr)$, and then perform the *k* integral to a $K_0$.